# How to POST multipart/form data?

Tags: python, python-requests

I've tried to create a dictionary with the names and values:

```
{
'name':'value',
'name':'value',
'name':'value',
...
}
```

Tried to yield the POST lines from the Chrome inspector:

```
yield '------WebKitFormBoundary48hldbqBzWdSiBZ6'
yield 'Content-Disposition: form-data; name="__EVENTTARGET"'
yield 'ctl00$ctl00$cphContent$cphContent$lnkEnter'
yield '------WebKitFormBoundary48hldbqBzWdSiBZ6'
yield 'Content-Disposition: form-data; name="__EVENTARGUMENT"'
yield ''
...
```

In this case, python crashed with the following error:

```
for k, vs in to_key_val_list(data)
ValueError: too many values to unpack
```

And I've also tried the regular form data POST:

```
name=value&name=value&name=value...
```

Could you tell me how to create the multipart body and how to POST it using requests?
There's no files to send, only name and values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's difficult to know exactly what you're trying to do without a more concrete example.

Your first example may work or may not depending on how you actually use it. Are you passing it into the files parameter?

Your second will never work. There is a specific header that needs to be set for `multipart/form-data` and it has to include the boundary, in this case `------WebKitFormBoundary48hldbqBzWdSiBZ6` or some string there-of. Next you should not pass a generator into the files parameter but instead pass it into the data parameter once you've correctly set the header.

Finally, if you're trying to perform a `multipart/form-data` POST then a URL-encoded POST will not work the same way unless your website is very flexible.